# Host multiple websites on single domain - folder wise on aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting

I want to have one S3 URL with index.html file and folders on bucket as folder1 and folder2.
Each folder contains build files of respective project.I want to click on folder1 link and go to respective website using AWS s3.

Folder1 link-> Project1
Folder2 link -> Project 2 and so on.

I have tried with creating Bucket on s3 and uploading build to two folders respectively according to project.I have one index.html with two links.
I have index.html file at each project level also.

I am not able to access projects on clicking on respective folder.
Can anyone suggest me something for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you expand on what issues you're seeing? :)

Comment: "I am not able to access projects on clicking on respective folder. Can anyone suggest something for this?" probably because you didn't give public access to these folders. Don't server static files this way. Use Cloudfront with S3, Google that. If you are talking about portfolio then use other services to host your portfolio, like Vercel or Github Pages.

Answer (score 0):

If the homepage is being served correctly by S3 but the others are not (for a number of reasons), then check the following:

- Do the objects exist in the S3 bucket. Check the filenames.
- Do the objects have public read access (preferably through the bucket policy).
- Does the HTML in your footer for the `href` go to a valid path. Be careful of relative vs absolute path.

Also check out these troubleshooting pages:

- [How can I troubleshoot the 404 "NoSuchKey" error from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/)
- [How do I troubleshoot 403 Access Denied errors from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)